Active X Controls change position on worksheet despite being software-fixed
the position of my controls change after clicking on them, despite my attempt to fix position by the code below. Is there anything else I should do? Please help.
Private Sub CalculateMe_Click()

Dim btn As Shape
Set btn = ActiveSheet.Shapes("CalculateMe")
btn.height = 30: btn.width = 75
btn.Top = 151.2: btn.Left = 422.4

 ' other code here

End Sub


Sorry, I should have mentioned that the controls don't move on my machine, only when the app runs on somebody's else machine.

Different machines have different monitors with different sizes and resolutions!!!

Had this issue several times in different variations - especially if you have a zoom factor on your monitor. Gave up usage of ActiveX controls completely, either using Form controls or, instead of buttons, use simple shapes.

This is because the screen resolution is different on the 2 machines.  The positions are contingent on the screen resolution, so you have to compensate for it.
